# Help understanding AM-GM use.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

So I was reading the solution of the following problem.

***A $100X100$ array is filled with numbers from ${1,2,...,100}$ ,such that each number appears exactly 100 times.Prove that there is some row or column which contains atleast 10 different numbers.***

In the solution it says that we can prove through AM-GM that each number appears in at least 20 rows-columns.I have proved this another way but i can't find how to apply AM-GM.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorics - possibly pigeon hole, 100 by 100 matrix with numbers from 1 to 100](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663677/combinatorics-possibly-pigeon-hole-100-by-100-matrix-with-numbers-from-1-to-1)

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950325/prove-that-there-exists-a-row-or-a-column-of-the-chessboard-which-contains-at-le

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say that the number appears in $a$ rows and $b$ columns. That means that it appears at most $ab$ times (intersections between these allowed rows and columns). By AM-GM, you have:

$$100 \le ab \le \left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2.$$

Therefore, $10 \le (a+b)/2$ which gives $a+b \ge 20$ as desired.