# Prove that there exists a row or a column of the chessboard which contains at least √n distinct numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probabilistic-method

> On each cell of an $n \times n$ chessboard, we write a number from $1, 2, 3, .
>  . . , n$ in such a way that each number appears exactly $n$ times. Prove
>   that there exists a row or a column of the chessboard which contains
>   at least $\sqrt{n}$ distinct numbers.

This question is dying for a proof by contradiction, but I can't seem to show how. When I searched through the Internet, there is the following hint:

> Assume each row and each column has less than $\sqrt{n}$ distinct numbers in
>   it. For each row or column, consider the number of distinct numbers in
>   it.

I feel like double counting is involved in the process, but what to count in two different ways? Also I can prove the statement with the probabilistic method but I would really like to learn the double counting approach.

Here is the other proof:

Choose a random row or column ($2n$ choices). Let $\textbf X$ be the number of distinct entries in it. Use the indicator variable $I_i$, for the existence of number $i$ in the block: $\textbf X = \sum I_i.$ Clearly, $E[I_i] = P[I_i = 1]$.  Then $P[I_i = 1] \geq 2\sqrt n / (2n) = 1/\sqrt n$. The lower bound is obtained if all the $i$ happens to be in some $\sqrt n$ edged square sub-matrix. Hence, by linearity $\textbf E[X] \geq \sqrt n$. This proves the existence.

Comment: For reference, and to help others, could you post your probability-based proof, either as part of your question, or perhaps as an answer? I would very much like to see it. Thanks.

Comment: @quasi I am posting it now

Comment: Shouldn't the sentence "The lower bound is obtained . . ." be moved to after the statement $P[i_1=1] \ge\;...\;$?

Comment: Well I think that depends on the perspective you want to look at the things:)  If you can derive the inequality, you can explain it later. If you can do the reasoning, you can derive it later. However, I think it would be more clear to do it in the way you suggest. I am changing it.

Comment: I follow now. Looks good! Thanks.

Comment: Do you leave the other $n^2-\frac 12n(n+1)=\frac 12n(n-1)$ squares blank?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So we have $n$ columns and $n$ rows. Each of these we call a line. So we have $2n$ lines $L_1,L_2,...,L_{2n}$ and suppose that each line has less than $\sqrt{n}$ different numbers ($d(L_i)<\sqrt{n}$).

Suppose number $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ appears in $c_k$ columns and $r_k$ rows. Then we see that $$r_k+c_k \geq 2\sqrt{n} .$$

(To prove this, notice that all $n$ appearances of $k$ in the chessboard must be in the $r_k \times c_k$-rectangle formed by the $r_k$ rows and the $c_k$ columns in which $n$ appears; thus $r_k c_k \geq n$. But the AM-GM inequality yields $r_k + c_k \geq 2 \sqrt{r_k c_k} \geq 2 \sqrt{n}$ since $r_k c_k \geq n$.)

So we have: $$2n\cdot \sqrt{n}>\sum _{i=1}^{2n} d(L_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n (r_k+c_k)\geq n\cdot (2\sqrt{n})$$

A contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain the claim $r_k+c_k\ge 2\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Imagine a square $\sqrt{n}\times \sqrt{n}$ filed with the same number. ''Clearly'' at this configuration is the minimum for $r_k+c_k$

Comment: Yes, I see. I think that mini-argument should be included in the proof.

Comment: Nice proof! (+1).

Comment: I actually made use of the mini square argument in the probabilistic proof. Seeing that it also works here is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added a nontrivial missing step into this answer; now it's a really nice proof.

Comment: I don't get it why is $r_kc_k\geq n$. Can this be proven by Iverson bracket notation? @darijgrinberg

Comment: @darijgrinberg    Ah, this is true beacuse of $$r_kc_k=(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)(b_1+b_2+...+b_n)=
a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n\geq n$$ if $a_i$ is indicator that $k$ is in
$i$-th row and similarly for $j$-th column $b_j$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice interpretation of the other answer here in terms of the [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method): it is showing that the expected number of distinct elements in a randomly chosen row or column is at least $\sqrt{n}$, from which it follows that *some* row or column has at least $\sqrt{n}$ distinct elements. Here is the formal argument.

Given an integer $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ let $r_k,c_k$ be the number of rows (resp. columns) that contain the integer $k$. Observe that $r_kc_k\geq n$, since all $n$ instances of $k$ are contained in an $r_k\times c_k$ "rectangle".

Let $\Omega=\{1,\ldots,n\}\times \{R,C\}$ be the set of rows or columns. Let $U$ be a uniformly random element of $\Omega$, and let $D$ be the number of distinct integers appearing in $U$. Then
$$
\mathbb E D = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb P(i\in D)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r_i+c_i}{2n}\geq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{r_ic_i}}{n}\geq \sqrt{n}. 
$$
It follows that there exists some $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $D(\omega)\geq \sqrt{n}$, as desired.