# Combinatorics pigeonhole principle with matrix

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let A be a 100 x 100 matrix such that every number from {1, 2, ... 100} shows in A exactly 100 times.

Prove that there's a row or a column with at least 10 different numbers.

The context is the Pigeonhole Principle.

EDIT: theres a solution to this questuion here: [Prove that there exists a row or a column of the chessboard which contains at least √n distinct numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950325/prove-that-there-exists-a-row-or-a-column-of-the-chessboard-which-contains-at-le)

but the problem is that I dont understand how to prove the part which is said to be "clearly

I couldn't solve it by myself, when trying every strategy I know for solving Pigeonhole problems.

Comment: Yes, this is actually the proof, although I dont understand how to prove the "clearly" part he mentions there

Comment: @DanielSegal Let me tell you, there are enough close voters (from review, typically) who won't look at the comments to see that you have additional questions. If you want your question to stay open, I suggest editing your question, including the link to the dupe target, and explicitly quote the part of the proof you want explained.

Comment: Try putting 8 lots of 11 plus one lot of 12 into each row - so each row consumes at least 11 of 9 different numbers.  The number can't appear that way in columns because arithmetic shows you'd run out of them

Comment: I've added a missing step into Aqua's answer over at the linked thread.