# How to prove with working with graph or tree that there must be a row or column that has more than $3$ different digits.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

Digits of $0,1,2,3,\dots ,9$ are written in a cells of a table in case that every digit is written $10$ times (it should be a $10 \times10$ table ). How to prove with working with graph or tree that there **must** be a row **or** column that has more than $3 $ different digits?

I tried to solve this with  drawing tables but it is not true, actually I could not because I do not know how to solve this problem with graph theory (and how it can be related to). Can you help me solve it in this way?

Comment: This problem was [previously asked on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950325/prove-that-there-exists-a-row-or-a-column-of-the-chessboard-which-contains-at-le), but the solutions given do not use graph theory.

Comment: @MikeEarnest but i must use graph :(